# How can I get the x y coordinate for the HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am coding a canvas. There is one player. It's holding a sword and keep spin.

I'd like to draw a black color and rectangle shape sword for the player.

The rectangle shape:

width = distance between right hand and left hand 
height = Player.swordLength

However, how can I get the end points of the sword?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var mouse = {
  x: c.width / 2,
  y: c.height / 2
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
})

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mouse.x = event.clientX;
  mouse.y = event.clientY;
});

class player {
  constructor(x, y, r, color, v) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.r = r
    this.v = v
    this.color = color
    this.swordLength = 200
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()

  }

  update() {
    this.draw()
    var dy = mouse.y - this.y
    var dx = mouse.x - this.x
    const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)

    var vx = Math.cos(angle) * this.v
    var vy = Math.sin(angle) * this.v

    if (Math.abs(vx) > Math.abs(dx)) {
      vx = dx
    }

    if (Math.abs(vy) > Math.abs(dy)) {
      vy = dy
    }
    this.x += vx
    this.y += vy
  }
}

class leftHand {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.color = color
    this.angle = 0
    this.r = r
    this.Area = 40
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  }

  update() {
    this.draw()
    this.x = Player.x + this.Area * Math.cos(this.angle / 180)
    this.y = Player.y + this.Area * Math.sin(this.angle / 180)
    this.angle += 30
  }
}

class rightHand {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.color = color
    this.angle = 90
    this.r = r
    this.Area = 40
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  }

  update() {
    this.draw()
    this.x = Player.x + this.Area * Math.cos(this.angle / 180)
    this.y = Player.y + this.Area * Math.sin(this.angle / 180)
    this.angle += 30
  }
}

class sword {
  constructor(Lx, Ly, Rx, Ry, color, Lsx, Lsy, Rsx, Rsy) {
    this.Lx = Lx
    this.Ly = Ly
    this.Rx = Rx
    this.Ry = Ry
    this.Lsx = Lsx
    this.Lsy = Lsy
    this.Rsx = Rsx
    this.Rsy = Rsy
    this.color = color
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(this.Lx, this.Ly);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Rx, this.Ry);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Rsx, this.Rsy);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Lsx, this.Lsy);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  }

  update() {
    this.draw()
    this.Lx = LeftHand.x
    this.Ly = LeftHand.y
    this.Rx = RightHand.x
    this.Ry = RightHand.y
    this.Lsx = LeftHand.x + Player.swordLength;
    this.Lsy = LeftHand.y + Player.swordLength;
    this.Rsx = RightHand.x + Player.swordLength;
    this.Rsy = RightHand.y + Player.swordLength;
  }
}

const Player = new player(c.width / 2, c.height / 2, 30, 'blue', 10)

const LeftHand = new leftHand(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  10,
  'red'
)

const RightHand = new rightHand(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180),
  10,
  'yellow'
)

const Sword = new sword(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180),
  'black',
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180),
)




function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
  Player.update()
  LeftHand.update()
  RightHand.update()
  Sword.update()
}

animate()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The end point of sword equal:

Left Hand Source = `the current point` **To be spin sword**

Right Hand Source = `the current point + Player.swordLength`

The `sword.update()` function should be like this:

```
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.Lx = LeftHand.x;
    this.Ly = LeftHand.y;
    this.Rx = RightHand.x;
    this.Ry = RightHand.y;

    this.Lsx = LeftHand.x;
    this.Lsy = LeftHand.y;
    this.Rsx = RightHand.x + Player.swordLength;
    this.Rsy = RightHand.y + Player.swordLength;
  }
```

And here is your code edited:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var mouse = { x: c.width / 2, y: c.height / 2 };

window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  mouse.x = event.clientX;
  mouse.y = event.clientY;
});

class player {
  constructor(x, y, r, color, v) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.v = v;
    this.color = color;
    this.swordLength = 200;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    this.draw();
    var dy = mouse.y - this.y;
    var dx = mouse.x - this.x;
    const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    var vx = Math.cos(angle) * this.v;
    var vy = Math.sin(angle) * this.v;

    if (Math.abs(vx) > Math.abs(dx)) {
      vx = dx;
    }

    if (Math.abs(vy) > Math.abs(dy)) {
      vy = dy;
    }
    this.x += vx;
    this.y += vy;
  }
}

class leftHand {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.r = r;
    this.Area = 40;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.x = Player.x + this.Area * Math.cos(this.angle / 180);
    this.y = Player.y + this.Area * Math.sin(this.angle / 180);
    this.angle += 30;
  }
}

class rightHand {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.angle = 90;
    this.r = r;
    this.Area = 40;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.x = Player.x + this.Area * Math.cos(this.angle / 180);
    this.y = Player.y + this.Area * Math.sin(this.angle / 180);
    this.angle += 30;
  }
}

class sword {
  constructor(Lx, Ly, Rx, Ry, color, Lsx, Lsy, Rsx, Rsy) {
    this.Lx = Lx;
    this.Ly = Ly;
    this.Rx = Rx;
    this.Ry = Ry;
    this.Lsx = Lsx;
    this.Lsy = Lsy;
    this.Rsx = Rsx;
    this.Rsy = Rsy;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.Lx, this.Ly);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Rx, this.Ry);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Rsx, this.Rsy);
    ctx.lineTo(this.Lsx, this.Lsy);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.Lx = LeftHand.x;
    this.Ly = LeftHand.y;
    this.Rx = RightHand.x;
    this.Ry = RightHand.y;

    this.Lsx = LeftHand.x;
    this.Lsy = LeftHand.y;
    this.Rsx = RightHand.x + Player.swordLength;
    this.Rsy = RightHand.y + Player.swordLength;
  }
}

const Player = new player(c.width / 2, c.height / 2, 30, "blue", 10);

const LeftHand = new leftHand(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  10,
  "red"
);

const RightHand = new rightHand(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180),
  10,
  "yellow"
);

const Sword = new sword(
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180),
  "black",
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(0 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(0 / 180),
  c.width / 2 + 40 * Math.cos(90 / 180),
  c.height / 2 + 40 * Math.sin(90 / 180)
);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  Player.update();
  LeftHand.update();
  RightHand.update();
  Sword.update();
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, the sword isn't spin

Comment: Ok, sorry misunderstanding. I will edit the answer

Comment: @Iwanttodesignwebsite I edited the code. Is that you want ?

Comment: Thank you. I change my logic and use 'drawImage' with sprite sheet. It's done.